# Change android drop down menu to a settings button

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Currently in my app there is a dropdown menu containing one option `Settings` using this icon in the upper right corner [image] I want to swap it out with this icon [image] and instead of causing a drop down just calling a new view on tap.

This is how i currently handle the settings menu

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, appSets.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set `android:showAsAction="always"` in your `res/menu/filename.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
      <item
         android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         android:showAsAction="always"
         andoid:title="@string/action_settings"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

and if you are using appcompatv7 library you just need to edit it a little bit

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
      <item
         android:id="@+id/action_settings"
         app:showAsAction="always"
         andoid:title="@string/action_settings"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to res/menu/main.xml and in item  `<item />` instead `android:icon="@drawable/new_pic"` use your drawable image